# Just bought a new laptop and need some help

Tags: lenovo, amd-graphics

I've just bought a new laptop, namely the Lenovo B51-80 (Intel® Core™ i7-6500U, AMD Radeon R5 M330
Intel® HD Graphics) without an OS because I want to install Ubuntu or maybe Linux Mint, as I'm a CS student but a total linux newbie. I've then read about the problems with AMD and I would appreciate some help regarding the ubuntu version to install and amd driver. I don't game, but I will need some 3D rendering.

So, I just tried ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop without installing, and the screen shows flickering lines and dots. This does not look good :(

Comment: why don't you install windows and use VirtualBox for Linux?

Comment: @lewis4u would that be better? I mean, I don't really need windows for anything

Comment: it all depends what exactly you want to do with that laptop....if it's only programming and learning i would recommend VirtualBox with VM Linux....and 3D Rendering you can do on host (your laptop) and you will avoid all the trouble with drivers! But that's is only my opinion!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that AMD drivers are kind of outdated, but you don't need to install them, just stick with the open source ones. To be sure everything is ok and not not wast time: Make a bootable usb with Ubuntu, boot from it and choose the option: try without installing, or something like that. This will open up a live session that will only load Ubuntu on the RAM and will not touch your HDD. Make sure all is working fine then you could install it.

Also as a rule of thumb: Some vendors work close with Canonical to certified their hardware and make sure Ubuntu works just fine on it. [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/) is a list. Your laptop is not there, but that doesn't mean there is something wrong.

Comment: Note: This live session option is also there for mint or whatever distro you wish to use, once your restart your pc, everything will be back to normal, again it only touches your RAM, unless you do something  to your files.

Comment: Are the open source ones installed during the installation of ubuntu? I already have ubuntu on my stick, tried it on my old laptop (I am at least somewhat prepared). Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, they come by default. Don't need to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Nice choice of OS, welcome.

Installing Ubuntu is a breeze, you will always gain from the experience.

This answer should get you going:

[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

Edit: updated link to question that is not a duplicate.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Your answer contains a link to a duplicate question. Can you update your link to the original question instead? It has better instructions with  more answer up-votes and is the better place for the OP to start reading.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix done. Thanks for the heads up!